# Drawing SVG images with an array of images.

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an array with names of images, I want to crate an svg canvas and position them in correct rows and columns so that it will not overlap. Here is my code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var imagesObjects = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","6.png","3.png","4.png","6.png","1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","6.png","1.png","2.png"];



var iconsArea = d3.select("#icons").data(imagesObjects)
                                            .enter()
                                            .append("svg:image")
                                            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
                                                console.log(d);
                                                return "images/"+d;
                                            })
                                            .attr("width", 20)
                                            .attr("height", 20)
                                            .attr("x", function(d, i){
                                                return i*10;
                                            })
                                            .attr("y",function(d, i){
                                                return i*10;
                                            });
    </script>
```

But When I run this, My  tags won't append to the canvas. All I get is a blank canvas. Can anyone point my mistake

Comment: maybe you could ask another question on placing the images and mark my answer as accepted? Or explain in what way the images should be placed so that i can update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you say svg canvas, because that are two different things, but you are appending `svg:image` so i assume you are working with an svg.

Is there an svg element with `id="icons"`? You have to select all the images you want create as a placeholder and bind the data to it. basically I just added the `.selectAll("image")`.

```
var iconsArea = d3.select("#icons").selectAll("image")
    .data(imagesObjects)
    .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
        console.log(d);
        return "images/"+d;
    })
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return i*10;
    })
    .attr("y",function(d, i){
        return i*10;
    });
```

Comment: Yes I am working with an SVG. and i do have a SVG with id="icons". Thanks your solution works. I may need a new algorithm to place the images correctly. :)

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept my answer ;)